# Apache 2 redirect based on condition with ServerName

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a virtual host for `www.domain.com` which redirect all to `https`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com *.domain.com

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

This will redirect all request from

- `domain.com` to `https://domain.com`
- `www.domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com`
- `*.domain.com` to `https://*.domain.com`

but i want to enforce `www` on `domain.com`.

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com [OR]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
```

but this is not working..

can someone help em to achieve this without having to create another `VirtualHost` just for `domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com *.domain.com

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.domain.com 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.domain.com  
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

The first Rewrite Rule will redirect all requests from both http://domain.com and http://www.domain.com to https://www.domain.com

The second Rewrite Rule will redirect all requests from http://*.domain.com to https://*.domain.com